# Repeate the sound each time a button is pressed

Tags: java, android, list, audio, android-mediaplayer

[image]I programmed a quiz with one question, 3 choices and one correct answer. When I press the right of the 3 Button (Choices) it plays the sound fine but when I click it again nothing happens. I want that the sound repeat it self each time the right button is clicked. I have a list named choices. There I have an IF query that every time one of the right choices is pressed it should repeat the sound. the part I want to inser the code is under the if(choice.getText().equals(mAnswer))

Thanks for looking. :)

```
         public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

private QuestionLibrary mQuestionLibrary = new QuestionLibrary();

private TextView mScoreView;
private TextView mQuestionView;
private Button mButtonChoice1;
private Button mButtonChoice2;
private Button mButtonChoice3;
private String mAnswer;
private int mScore = 0;
private int mQuestionNumber = 0;
Dialog dialog;
TextView closeButton;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sample);


    createDialog();
    Button dialogButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dialogbtn);
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.show();

        }
    });

    closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    TextView shareTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.share);
    shareTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            myIntent.setType("text/plain");
            myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Hello!");
            myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My highscore in Quizzi is very high! I bet you can't beat me except you are cleverer than me. Download the app now! https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=amapps.impossiblequiz");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Share with:"));
        }
    });

    mQuestionLibrary.shuffle();


    setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nav_action));
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // Able to see the Navigation Burger "Button"

    ((NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nv1)).setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_stats:
                    startActivity(new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class));
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_about:
                    startActivity(new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu3.class));
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });

    mScoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score_score);
    mQuestionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    mButtonChoice1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice1);
    mButtonChoice2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice2);
    mButtonChoice3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice3);

    final List<Button> choices = new ArrayList<>();
    choices.add(mButtonChoice1);
    choices.add(mButtonChoice2);
    choices.add(mButtonChoice3);

    updateQuestion();








    for (final Button choice : choices) {



        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.stop();

            }

        });

        choice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (choice.getText().equals(mAnswer)) {


                    try {
                        mp.prepare();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mp.start();






                    updateScore();
                    updateQuestion();
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Wrong... Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("score", mScore); // pass score to Menu2
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}

private void updateQuestion() {
    if (mQuestionNumber < mQuestionLibrary.getLength()) {
        mQuestionView.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice1.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice1(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice2.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice2(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice3.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice3(mQuestionNumber));
        mAnswer = mQuestionLibrary.getCorrectAnswer(mQuestionNumber++);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Last Question! You are very intelligent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
        intent.putExtra("score", mScore);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

private void updateScore() {
    mScoreView.setText(String.valueOf(++mScore));

    SharedPreferences mypref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    int highScore = mypref.getInt("highScore", 0);

    if (mScore > highScore) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mypref.edit();
        editor.putInt("highScore", mScore);
        editor.apply();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void createDialog() {
    dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setTitle("Tutorial");
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_menu1_1);
    closeButton = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.closeTXT);
}
```

}

Comment: Try add Media player inside onclickListener

Comment: Can not resolve method error under: choice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Comment: what method can not resolve the onclickListener?

Comment: The     choice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() method

Comment: and if you do this `if (choice.getText().equals(mAnswer)) {
                    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sample);
                    mp.start();
}`

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'create(anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener, int)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So try do this:

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.stop();
            
        }

        });

choice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (choice.getText().equals(mAnswer)) {
                    mp.prepare();
                    mp.start();


                    updateScore();
                    updateQuestion();
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                   

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Wrong... Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("score", mScore); // pass score to Menu2
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
```

**Other way**:

```
choice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (choice.getText().equals(mAnswer)) {
                        try {
            mp.reset();
            AssetFileDescriptor afd;
            afd = getAssets().openFd("your_sound.mp3");
            mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
                        updateScore();
                        updateQuestion();
                        Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
                       
    
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Wrong... Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
                        Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
                        intent.putExtra("score", mScore); // pass score to Menu2
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Explanation:

Acording to this [android developers link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) you need to follow the diagram.
So you need to `prepare()`, `start()`, `stop()` to replay sound. Because you don't `prepare()` and don't `stop()` the media player not be ready to replay.

Comment: App force closes when I hit an answer, I updated my code!

Comment: what is the logcat? @Alan

Comment: And try add the `mp.setOnCompletionListener()` outsider the for loop

Comment: caused by at shapy.appz.QuizActivity$6.onClick(QuizActivity.java:145)

Comment: I copied it outside, app still crashes... The mp.prepare() is the problem

Comment: The full logcat is too long. I can`t find the caused by section but mp.prepare() is the problem

Comment: and if you remove `prepare()` ?

Comment: If I rmove prepare, the sound only appears on the first questions than not anymore. Now I have seen that prepare alone gives me this error: Unhandled exception: java.io.IOException then when i click on the alarm simbol it is the possibility with try catch method but that does not work either

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151421/discussion-between-bruno-ferreira-and-alan).

Comment: Help me app crashes!

Comment: what is the problem?